# Average over 2000 values with PySpark Dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, bigdata, apache-spark-sql

I have a PySpark dataframe with about a billion rows. I want to average over every 2000 values, like average of rows with indeces 0-1999, average of rows with indeces 2000-3999, and so on. How do I do this? Alternatively, I could also average 10 values for every 2000, like average of rows with indeces 0-9, average of rows with indeces 2000-2009, and so on. The purpose of this is to downsample the data. I don't currently have an index row, so if I need this, how do I do it?

Comment: You have to partition data in such a way that 2000 rows are partitioned as one partition and then use mapPartition api to get the average

Answer (score 0):

You can use `monotonically_increasing_id()` to generate row ids, divide it and use a ceiling function to generate an id over whatever interval you want. Then use window function to partition over that id and generate the average. For example, something like following should work, assuming your dataframe is `data` and you want to average over the column `value`.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
val partitionWindow = Window.partitionBy($"rowId")
data.withColumn("rowId", floor(monotonically_increasing_id()/2000.0)).withColumn("avg", avg(data("value")) over(partitionWindow)).show()
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I don't think this will work because `monotonically_increasing_id()` is guaranteed to be increasing but not necessarily continuous. So you may have id value 0 for row 1 and 1000000 for row 2.

Comment: @pault huh I tried it on a couple dataframes I was working with and it seemed to generate consecutive numbers. But after searching a bit, it does seem like the function has lots of problems. I think, `row_number()` from spark-sql should do the trick otherwise.

Comment: You probably need a combo of the two, but I imagine it would be slow.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it by determining the row number for each value.

1. Create a unique, increasing `id` column using [`pyspark.sql.functions.monotonically_increasing_id()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.monotonically_increasing_id).
2. Create a [`pyspark.sql.Window()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Window) that does an `orderBy()` on the `id` column.
3. Use [`pyspark.sql.functions.row_number()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.row_number) over the window to get the row number for each value.
4. Divide the row_number - 1 (because it starts at 1) by the number of groups and take the floor to get the group number.
5. `groupBy()` the group number and compute the average.

---

Here is an example:

**Create Example Data**

For this example, I will create a dataframe of 5 consecutive values starting at each multiple of 10 from 10 to 40 (inclusive). The group size in this example will be 5- we will want the average of 5 consecutive values.

```python
data = map(
    lambda y: (y, ),
    reduce(
        list.__add__,
        [range(x, x+5) for x in range(10, 50, 10)]
    )
)
df = sqlCtx.createDataFrame(data, ["col1"])
df.show()
#+----+
#|col1|
#+----+
#|  10|
#|  11|
#|  12|
#|  13|
#|  14|
#|  20|
#|  21|
#|  22|
#|  23|
#|  24|
#|  30|
#|  31|
#|  32|
#|  33|
#|  34|
#|  40|
#|  41|
#|  42|
#|  43|
#|  44|
#+----+
```

**Add ID Columns**

I'm showing this step to demonstrate the fact that `monotonically_increasing_id()` is not guaranteed to be sequential.

```python
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
df = df.withColumn('id', f.monotonically_increasing_id())
df.show()
#+----+----------+
#|col1|        id|
#+----+----------+
#|  10|         0|
#|  11|         1|
#|  12|         2|
#|  13|         3|
#|  14|         4|
#|  20|         5|
#|  21|         6|
#|  22|         7|
#|  23|         8|
#|  24|         9|
#|  30|8589934592|
#|  31|8589934593|
#|  32|8589934594|
#|  33|8589934595|
#|  34|8589934596|
#|  40|8589934597|
#|  41|8589934598|
#|  42|8589934599|
#|  43|8589934600|
#|  44|8589934601|
#+----+----------+
```

**Compute the group number**

```python
from pyspark.sql import Window
group_size = 5
w = Window.orderBy('id')
df = df.withColumn('group', f.floor((f.row_number().over(w) - 1) / group_size))\
    .select('col1', 'group')
df.show()
#+----+-----+
#|col1|group|
#+----+-----+
#|  10|    0|
#|  11|    0|
#|  12|    0|
#|  13|    0|
#|  14|    0|
#|  20|    1|
#|  21|    1|
#|  22|    1|
#|  23|    1|
#|  24|    1|
#|  30|    2|
#|  31|    2|
#|  32|    2|
#|  33|    2|
#|  34|    2|
#|  40|    3|
#|  41|    3|
#|  42|    3|
#|  43|    3|
#|  44|    3|
#+----+-----+
```

**Get the average per group**

```python
df.groupBy('group').agg(f.avg('col1').alias('avg')).show()
#+-----+----+
#|group| avg|
#+-----+----+
#|    0|12.0|
#|    1|22.0|
#|    2|32.0|
#|    3|42.0|
#+-----+----+
```